# Why Kafka-streams Produced needs a serde, not serializer

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

It's been a while I am using Kafka streams and still don't know why when we declare a `Produced`:

```java
        public static <K, V> Produced<K, V> with(Serde<K> keySerde, Serde<V> valueSerde) {
            return new Produced(keySerde, valueSerde, (StreamPartitioner)null, (String)null);
        }
```

we should specify KeySerde and valueSerde instead of keySerializer and valueSerializer.

Produced is used only to write into a topic.

When we read again from the topic we similarly declare a `Consumed` that requires serdes as well instead of deserializers.

Why ?

Answer (score 0):

A serde wraps both serializer and deserializer classes. Not all KStreams operations only consume or produce, so it's a convinence class, and the API is consistent rather than exposing underlying consumer/producer API.

Comment: For my case, only the `.to()` method requires an implicit produced, it only writes in the topic. If our application is only a producer of the topic, no need to define a deserializer

Comment: I agree. Dont know what else to tell you other than to create a Kafka JIRA if you really want to see the API improved or docs are unclear. As mentioned, you will never see a Serializer or Deserializer interface as part of the API, in order to keep the API consistent. I.e. you do need a serde set in `StreamsConfig` default props, which is used to consume, and this is often extract to a variable between the config and any `.to()` usage in code, therefore your code is not "only a producer"